# Magento- how to replace menu text with menu image

Tags: magento

In magento  how to add a icon in menu like home icon contact us
i need to replace the text with an image am not good in magento please help me to find a solution

Comment: This is not really a Magento question, more a CSS one.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not built into Magento but depends entirely on the theme that you are using. Some themes do offer icons in the menu.

You can do it in the code however but that needs some html and css skills